# OData Get Header Value From Response

Tags: header, response, odata

I am using OData together with JQuery. My problem here is that I need to retrieve the Header as I need the Header value. Do you guys know the syntax?

My codes are as follow:

```
      OData.request( {headers: { "X-CSRF-Token" :"Fetch" }, requestUri:queryserviceUriNew, user: uname, password: pword }, 
      function (data, response) 
     { 
        //Success Callback (received data is a Feed): 
   alert("Retrieved.");

   alert(response);
        // This is the object that hold the response, I need to capture the header value for "x-csrf-token"

      }
```

Thank you experts!

Answer (score 1):

In case there's someone else looking for the answer, the syntax is:

var header_value;
// variable = variable_hold_httpResponse.headers['header_item_that_you_want_to_get'];
header_value =  **response.headers['x-csrf-token'];**

Cheers!